# Fire an event when something is added to queue or array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, dom-events

I am writing a program in Javascript, CoffeeScript and jQuery to be exact.  I have one function that is adding things to a queue as they come in from the network.  What I want is for when something is added to this queue for an event to fire to tell another function to start removing items from the queue.  What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
var Queue = {
    listeners: [],
    objs: [],
    add: function(item) {
        objs.push(item);
        $.each(listeners, function() {
            listeners.added(item);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could inherit from Array and just reimplement the functions that you need (`constructor`and `push`)

```
class Queue extends Array
  constructor : (args...) ->
    @_listeners = []
    super(args...)

  onAdd : (fn) ->
    @_listeners.push fn

  push : (args...) ->
    fn(args...) for fn in @_listeners
    super(args...)

# Use it like this : 

q = new Queue
q.onAdd (args...) -> console.log("l1", args)
q.onAdd (args...) -> console.log("l2", args)

q.push(32)
q.push(52)

console.log '-'

for v in q
  console.log v

# Output : 
#
# l1 [ 32 ]
# l2 [ 32 ]
# l1 [ 52 ]
# l2 [ 52 ]
# -
# 32
# 52
```